# How can I tell if a specific Bluetooth device is connected to my iOS device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I've seen this asked several times for Android, but never iOS.  Is there any way to enumerate the currently-connected Bluetooth devices, or if not, to test for a specific one?  We're trying to build an app that can detect when it loses connectivity with a particular audio device.

For the record, it doesn't need to actually do anything with the device.  It just needs to know if it's connected or not.

Another less-helpful way way would be if we can detect which is the currently-selected audio output.  The only down-side is technically you can be connected to it and still route the audio through something else (headphones, AirPlay, etc.) so it's not really giving us what we want, but it's better than nothing (if this is possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of iOS 5.0 you can use the **CoreBluetooth** framework. Have a look at the **CBCentralManager** class. This class lets you retrieve a list of connected devices.

Comment: Can't stand the Apple docs because it wasn't clear what was in the array, but digging around, I found the NSPeripheral class which looks to be exactly what I want.  So for now, I'm marking yours as accepted.  However, technically I haven't tested this yet.  If there are any issues, I may reverse that.  (Doubtful I'd have to or others would have commented on this.  Their silence sort of endorses your answer.)

Comment: I don't know what NSPeripheral is. It's not in the iOS or OS X docs.

Comment: Typo. CBPeripheral, not NSPeripheral. Sorry.